# Validate variables from another bash script

Tags: bash, shell, validation

I have a script that asks for the user to enter a username and password. I want to compare the input to the username and password variables stored in a passwords.txt file. I tried using source but it does not give me access to the variables. Here are my parts of my files below:

passwords.txt

```
 #!/bin/bash 
 username="username"
 password="password"
```

script.bash

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo "Enter username"
 read -r user
 echo "Enter password"
 read -r pass
 source passwords.txt

 if("$user" == "$username" && "$pass" == "$password") then 
      echo "You have successfully logged in"
 else 
      echo "You entered the wrong credentials"
 fi
```

If you can, please help me figure out how to compare the two variables in different files.

Comment: The syntax for the `if` statement is incorrect, is this the actual code you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with sourcing, but with the syntax of your `if` statement.

That said, storing plain-text passwords in files and prompting users for passwords typed visibly are both practices to be avoided for security reasons.

With that out of the way, here's the Bash code that shows the proper form of the conditional:

```
 echo "Enter username"
 read -r user
 echo "Enter password"
 read -r pass
 source passwords.txt

 if [[ "$user" == "$username" && "$pass" == "$password" ]]; then 
      echo "You have successfully logged in"
 else 
      echo "You entered the wrong credentials"
 fi
```

Generally, consider using [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) to find syntax problems in your shell code.

In your specific case, as you point out in a comment, shellcheck.net wouldn't have helped, however:

`(...)` as a conditional passed to `if` *is* valid in principle, for executing a *command* whose exit code to test (although enclosing in `(...)` is typically *not* needed for that, because all that does is run the command in a *subshell*).

By contrast, you were looking to evaluate an *expression*, which is what syntax `[[ ... ]]` is for - see the [Bash manual online](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) or section `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` in `man bash`.

Comment: Well answered, mklement0.  Ashley, if this is a professional program, you'll want to run through a tutorial or blog post on how to handle secure passwords in bash.

Comment: Thank you @mklemento0 this works now! I actually did run the code through shellcheck.net before I used source and it did not give me any errors. And I am aware that this is not best practice but this is for an assignment that I am completing and this is part of the problem that was requested.

Comment: @Ashley Glad to hear it; re use of shellcheck.net: understood - please see my update.

Comment: Thanks again @mklement0 I see the difference in the two if statements now